# Biber in tool mode does not sort fields alphabetically (anymore)

Tags: biber, sorting

Biber in tool mode used to sort fields *within* entries (not: entries in the BIB file!) alphabetically by default. Newer versions of Biber apply rather strange sorting by default. Is it possible to get back alphabetic sorting?

For all examples I ran `biber --tool --output_file out.bib input.bib`.

**Input:**

```
@REPORT{Self2016,
  DATE      = {2016},
  TITLE     = {The title},
  AUTHOR    = {Self, My}
}
```

Biber 2.5 *and* 2.6 sort correctly:

```
@REPORT{Self2016,
  AUTHOR = {Self, My},
  DATE = {2016},
  TITLE = {The title},
}
```

However, other fields are not sorted alphabetically, for example `URL`:

**Input:**

```
@REPORT{Self2016,
  DATE      = {2016},
  TITLE     = {The title},
  AUTHOR    = {Self, My},
  URL       = {http://example.net}
}
```

Biber 2.5 sorts correctly:

```
@REPORT{Self2016,
  AUTHOR = {Self, My},
  DATE = {2016},
  TITLE = {The title},
  URL = {http://example.net},
}
```

Biber 2.6 does not (`URL` should be last):

```
@REPORT{Self2016,
  AUTHOR = {Self, My},
  URL = {http://example.net},
  DATE = {2016},
  TITLE = {The title},
}
```

Biber 2.7 (beta) behaves like Biber 2.6. The strange sorting is not limited to `URL` fields but applies to `INSTITUTION` and `LOCATION` as well (and maybe others).

Is there an option to enforce alphabetic sorting of the fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Four years later, I found the answer myself, at the very end of [Section 3.13. Tool Mode](https://ctan.mc1.root.project-creative.net/biblio/biber/documentation/biber.pdf) in the manual:

> The order of the fields when writing BibTeX data is controlled by the `--output-field-order` option. This is a comma-separated list of fields or field classes and fields will be output to entries in the order specified. Any unspecified fields will be output in sorted order after the specified fields.

The default is (from `biber -help`):

> By default, its value is 'options,abstract,names,lists,dates'.

As all unspecified fields are output in sorted order automatically, the trick is to set the option specifying *no* fields. Passing no value throws an error, but passing a whitespace character works. So the solution is:

```
biber --tool --output_file=out.bib input.bib --output-field-order=" "
```