# Biber tool mode: specify output field order in config file?

Tags: biber, sorting

I often use `biber`’s tool mode to sort entries in a bibfile, following [Using Bibtool to sort a bib file by types and keys alphabetically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426341/using-bibtool-to-sort-a-bib-file-by-types-and-keys-alphabetically/426370#426370).  I like to have the most salient fields of each entry listed first, so I pass `--output-field-order="author,title,dates,options,names,lists"` at the commandline (as discussed in e.g. [Biber in tool mode does not sort fields alphabetically (anymore)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334498/biber-in-tool-mode-does-not-sort-fields-alphabetically-anymore)).  However, it’s a bit inconvenient having to explicitly give this every time, and I’m passing a config file anyway — so I wonder if I could somehow give this in there, instead of via `--output-field-order`. **Is there some way to specify the output field order from within the config file?**

Answer (score 2):

Currently, this isn't possible I'm afraid as the command-line options are separate from the config file options. The latter are really so that you can set the options that usually come from a `.bcf`, in tool mode.